# The wind is blowing from the fan blades. (please correct this sentence into a better one)

Tags: american-english

The wind is blowing from the fan blades. (please correct this sentence into a better one, thank you~)

Comment: Explaining what you mean by "better" might help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, fan blades blow air, not wind. Other than idiomatic usages, *wind* is air movement by force of nature.

You could say:

> The fan (blades) are blowing (circulating) air around the room.

Outside of a technical explanation, would not need to use *blades* as it is understood a fan has blades.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with user3169 as to the use of "wind" versus "air' in this context. However, if you want to keep the integrity of your sentence, you could revise it from this:

> "*The wind* is blowing from the fan blades."

to this:

> "***Air*** is blowing from the fan blades."

However, I would like to add that your sentence could be more meaningful and more concise with the addition of modifiers and phrases.